# Set X-Robots-Tag on development and staging servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, conditional-statements, setenv

Adding this to an older system and am trying to do it in the .htaccess file.

```
# Prevent search engine indexing on dev sites:
SetEnvIf Host myliveserver\.com$ isproduction 
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive" env!=isproduction
```

Running on Apache 2.2.22 with mod_setenvif

Getting a dreaded 500.
If I remove the conditional `env!=isproduction` it runs.
What am I missing about the conditional clause?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities for a `500` status code

- mod_header isn't enabled
- according to [`Header`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header)

> **Syntax:** Header [condition] set|append|merge|add|unset|echo|edit header [value] [replacement] [early|env=[!]variable]
> ...
> **env=[!]varname**
> The directive is applied if and only if the environment variable varname exists. *A ! in front of varname reverses the test*, so the directive applies only if varname is unset.

So, your header directive should be

```
Header set ... env=!isproduction
```

Comment: mod_header is enabled.
I got the syntax from the Apache docs. I'm just confused as to what is wrong with my example, which I believe follows that syntax.

Comment: @lonkoenig Look at the second part of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Ah.. there it is...
`=!` vs `!=`
The NOT is applied to the variable, not the equality.